# Vue.js handler property of watch object

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I was wondering If there was a way that I can assign a function to the handler property of my object in Watch? currently I have all my code in the handler itself, but ideally would just like to say something like `handler: this.handleChange` and have `handleChange` be a function inside the methods property of my Vue component.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could refactor the handler code in a separate method and call that method inside your handler like :

```
handler(){
  this.handleChange();
}
```